# ntdll.dll allocation error in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ntdll

I have a properly running application developed in Visual Studio 2010 using several C++ libraries. I copied the necessary files onto my laptop to work on it on my own time and set up the environment required (VS2010, ITK, VTK, Boost, Qt, FANN, Waffles). The code that worked properly on my work computer gives run time error on my laptop and I am unable to figure out the problem.

When I run the code, it breaks giving an " unhandled exception at **** (ntdll.dll)  - access violation reading location **** " (the code window in which the error appears is calloc_impl.c). The call stack shows -    ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap(). When I try to see the symbol load information for ntdll, the .pdb file is loaded from the Microsoft Public Symbols server (it could not be found on my computer, neither in system32 or the application folder).

Is this somehow related to the performance limits of my laptop? Or is the environment that I set up not complete somehow? I cannot post snapshots of the code because it is work related, but I hope I have made my problem clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps one of these libraries were not built with Visual Studio 2010 or you have the wrong versions of the dlls in your path on the laptop. My guess is the heap is corrupted because of a CRT mismatch.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks! I don't think it's the libraries, because I used VS2010 on all of them. If I have the wrong version of the dlls, how can I confirm and correct that?

Comment: dependency walker. http://www.dependencywalker.com/ Carefully inspect the versions of the CRT dlls.